# Java ProcessBuilder not working with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: java, wkhtmltopdf, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I'm trying to generate a pdf from webpage, invoking wkhtmltopdf through java ProcessBuilder on Centos OS. The problem is that when I run a simple class with a main method the process terminates with:

```
Command has terminated with status: 139
Output:

Error: Loading pages (1/6) ....
```

and creates an empty pdf file (size 0B)

I've included a method that prints the arguments with which I invoke the wkhtmltopdf in the class and when I copy the command and run it in bash it works and creates the pdf. Even more: when I run the exact same class in windows it works just fine. What can cause this error code 139? Could it be a bug in wkhtmltopdf or I am doing something wrong?

Here's some more information:

OS:

```
[root@host sandbox]# uname -a
Linux xxxxxx.com 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 6 03:10:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@host bin]# ./wkhtmltopdf --version
Name:
  wkhtmltopdf 0.12.0 03c001de254b857f08eba80b62d4b6490ffed41d
```

Command I am trying to run with process builder:

```
 /root/wk/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf --window-status export-ready 
     --encoding UTF-8 
     --custom-header username username
     --custom-header password pass
     --run-script "<some correctly escaped js>" 
     http://xx.xx.xx.xx/url?param1=1&param2=2 
     /root/sandbox/test.pdf
```

Code for pdf generation:

```
public String exportToPdf(final String bookmarkableUrl) {
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    final String fullUrl = "http://" + hostName + ":" + port + bookmarkableUrl;

    // .html extension at the end is very important - wkhtmltopdf won't read
    // the file if not there
    String generatedPdfPath = tempDirPath + "/EMF/" + uuid;
    try {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command(prepareCommandArguments(fullUrl, generatedPdfPath + PDF_FILE_EXTENSION));
        Process start = processBuilder.start();
        // One has to handle the error stream 
        handleStream(start.getErrorStream());
        handleStream(start.getInputStream());
        // Wait until process is executed.
        start.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while generating PDF", e);
    }
    return generatedPdfPath;
}
```

**EDIT:** Adding the code that I use for creating the list with command arguments:

```
private List<String> prepareCommandArguments(String inputUrl, String outputUrl) {
    List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<>(15);
    // absolute path to the wkhtmltopdf executable
    arguments.add(wkhtmltopdfLocation);
    // Wait until window.status is equal to this string before rendering page
    arguments.add("--window-status");
    arguments.add("export-ready");
    // Set the default text encoding, for input
    arguments.add("--encoding");
    arguments.add("UTF-8");
    // Set an additional HTTP header for system username
    arguments.add("--custom-header");
    arguments.add("username");
    arguments.add(exportUsername);
    // Set an additional HTTP header for system user password 
    arguments.add("--custom-header");
    arguments.add("password");
    arguments.add(exportPassword);
    // Run this additional javascript after the page is done loading
    // Used to remove irrelevant divisions and spanning of 
    // the html page, leaving only the print preview of the document
    arguments.add("--run-script");
    arguments.add(getScriptFromFile(jsFilePath));
    // Bookmarkable url of the document 
    arguments.add(inputUrl);    
    // Path to the generated pdf
    arguments.add(outputUrl);
    return arguments;
}
```

Output of System.out.println(processBuilder.command()) just before Process.start() :

```
/root/wk/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf, --window-status, export-ready, --encoding, UTF-8, --custom-header, username, admin, --custom-header, password, admin, --run-script, "\$('.idoc-comments-column').remove(); \$('.idoc-left-column').remove(); \$('.idoc-left-column').remove(); \$('#topHeader').remove(); \$('#header').remove(); \$('.tree-header.breadcrumb_header').remove(); \$('.idoc-middle-column.pull-left.idoc-first-row').remove(); \$('.idoc-middle-column.pull-left').remove(); \$('.pull-left.text-center').remove(); \$('html').addClass('print-override-overflow'); \$('.idoc-editor').css('width', '80%'); \$('.idoc-editor').css('font-size', '14px'); \$('.idoc-editor').css('max-width', 'none'); \$('.idoc-editor').css('margin-left', '10%'); \$('.idoc-editor').css('margin-right', '10%'); \$('.idoc-editor').css('margin-top', '5%'); \$('.idoc-editor').css('margin-bottom', '5%');", http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/url/page.jsf?param1=1&param2=2, /root/sandbox/file.pdf
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `prepareCommandArguments`?

Comment: @A4L I've added the code, it's nothing special, just adding the args in a List<String>.

Comment: Your `getScriptFromFile` method does it return a String enclosed inside double quotes. And are you sure that the script file itself doesn't have any double quotes which may prematurely terminate the outer double quotes

Comment: According to [this post](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/issues/20) it seems to be a segmentation fault in the programm, thus a bug. And according to [this post](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=1168#c2) an update to another version has solved the issue.

Comment: @shazin Yes, the script is in double quotes, all OS specific symbols are escaped correctly (like jQuery's $) and there are no double quotes inside I use only ' inside. I haven't included it because it's lenghty.

Comment: @A4L Thanks, but I saw that post and I'm running version 0.12.0 of the tool.

Comment: @Ivo so it seems the bug was introduced with a version after `0.9.9` (ofcource if that is the same location in the programm where the the seg fault occurs) it might aswell be another bug wich causes another seg fault somewehre else in the programm, you might want to give that `0.9.9` version a try and see it works for you.

Comment: @A4L Yeah, the problem, however is that I am creating a pdf from pretty complex page which can't be handled by older versions of wkhtmltopdf (which use older version of the Qt web kit). Should I try perhaps installing a X server as that post suggests as workaround?

Comment: @Ivo, no luck, I would try to narrow down the source of the problem by trying to run the command with as less argements as possible once from command line and once using ProcessBuilder and after each successfull run adding the next argument. Try first with that js script one, also make sure your script is correctly escaped.

Comment: What's the output of `System.out.println(processBuilder.command())` if placed right before `processBuilder.start()`?

Comment: @pingw33n I've included the info in the question.

Comment: I think you don't need to do any shell-escaping with `ProcessBuilder`. Try passing the JS code as is without the dollar sign escaped and double quotes.

Comment: @pingw33n That actually worked, removed the escaped symbols from the script. Please post as answer so I can accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please let me know the JDK Vendor of the VM you are trying to run this command with. If it is other than SUN then it can be an issue. I remember having experience with JDK with IBM Vendor in AIX Operating system having a issue where it adds additional signal quotes surrounding all the commands in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do any shell-escaping with `ProcessBuilder`. Try passing the JS code as is without the dollar sign escaped and double quotes.